# Automatic saveloop in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So i have this code which saves an Excel file every 30 minutes after i open it. It works out great but when a database file is opened the Excel file is locked and cant save. The loop is broken and i have to restart the excel file to make it work again. Anyone got a solution? Here is the code btw:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "SaveWb"

End Sub

Sub SaveWb()
Workbooks("Shared.xlsm").Save
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "SaveWb"

On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your "On Error Resume Next" needs to be placed before the part of the code that might generate the error. In this case, it needs to be before the Workbooks(...).Save line.

Comment: How is the database file opening the workbook? Does it need Read/Write access? If the database file is strictly reading from the workbook then the best solution would be to have it open a ReadOnly copy. This way the original workbook should never become locked by the outside process.

Comment: The database file only needs to read the file, im will try it out if Access can accept a read only file as linked table.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixed my problem, you can replace the filepath with your own.

```
Public Function FileInUse(sFileName) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Open sFileName For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
Close #1
FileInUse = IIf(Err.Number > 0, True, False)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Sub SaveWb()
myFilePath = "\\server\Klaverkaas Algemeen\Database Access\BackEnd\Database Klaverkaas klein.accdb"
If FileInUse(myFilePath) Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "SaveWb"
Else
    Workbooks("Shared.xlsm").Save
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "SaveWb"
End If
End Sub
```

And use this in myworkbook

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "SaveWb"

End Sub
```